# Accessing passed Worksheet object from C# to F# library

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

I am trying to process data in an Excel worksheet passed from a C# class to an F# class library.
The C# project is an Excel AddIn project the F# class is this.

```ml
namespace DataLib
open System
open System.Reflection
open System.Collections.Generic
open FSharpx.TypeProviders.Excel
open Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices
open System.IO
open System.Linq
open System.Text
open System.Windows.Forms
open Microsoft.Office.Core
open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
open Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel
type sheet = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
type Class1() = 
    member this.X = "F#"
    member this.Readsheet (sh:obj)=
        let sht = sh:?>Worksheet// exception here
        let v=sh.Cells.[1,1] // Exception COM object does not have Cells property etc...
        sh.Range.Item(1,1).ToString() //error here ca
```

So if I call the class from C# like this

```cs
using DataLib;

public void useExcel(sh as Excel.Worksheet) //Excel.Worksheet is Excel Interop object
{
      Class1 one = new Class1()
      one.Readsheet(sh) //Exception thrown here in F# class
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to actually ask your _question_...

Comment: My apologies, I have eddited the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interop between F# and C# isn't a problem. You have various errors in your F# class:

1. You cast an Object `sh` to Worksheet `sht`, but mistakenly use `sh` instead of `sht` later.
2. `Range` doesn't have `Item` property.
3. You add virtually everything related to Excel programming into the project. You only need `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` in this example. It's better to remove unnecessary `open` commands, especially `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel` which is opened after `Interop.Excel` could have objects of the same names but have incompatible fields/interfaces.
4. You should pass a `Worksheet` instead of an `obj` to avoid downcasting.

A minimal F# example that works:

```ml
namespace DataLib

open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

type Class1() = 
    member this.X = "F#"
    member this.Readsheet (sh: Worksheet) =
        let v = sh.Cells.[1, 1]
        sh.Range(1, 1).ToString()
```

Moreover, your C# syntax is a bit off, you need something like:

```cs
// Add "using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;" 
// and "using DataLib;" to namespace declarations
public void useExcel(Worksheet sh) // Worksheet is Excel Interop object
{
    Class1 one = new Class1();
    one.Readsheet(sh);
}
```

Comment: Mixing C# with VB.NET and F# thanks but surprisingly this does not work. Will not even compile in F#, it tells me the field, constructor or member 'Cells' not defined. Very surprising !

Comment: Did you get rid of all unnecessary open commands especially `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel`. Two dlls have common class names but their classes are possibly incompatible.

Comment: Thanks, it was just slightly more complicated, not only do you need to remove the open Microsoft.Tools.Office.Excel, you need to remove the refrence to the PIA VSTO assembly from the F# library references as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is a bit more complicated. I added a reference to the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel framework to the F# Library project. That is a no no! It will give compiler errors. In F#, avoid referencing the Microsoft.Tools.Office.Excel namespace as well in your F# library if you are writing an F# library that is part of a VSTO C# project. Otherwise you will have problems! So only add the reference to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly to your project and open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in the F# file.